# When does $\gcd(a^n+b^n,|a-b|)=\gcd(a+b,|a-b|)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

(I'll assume $a>b$ now)

As title, when does $\gcd(a^n+b^n,a-b)=\gcd(a+b,a-b)$?

I know that $\gcd(a+b,a-b)=$ either $\gcd(a, b)$ or $2\gcd(a, b)$, but I do not know how to proceed. It would be so much better if $a^n+b^n$ is replaced with $a^n-b^n$... haha. And no, this is not a homework question.

Thank you for the help

Comment: Actually now that I reread the question, it doesn't seem to be easy to state/solve, as there're 3 variables and $\gcd$ involved. Perhaps it will be easier to find cases where LHS $\neq$ RHS instead. If this is too general or hard to solve I will remove the post. Still, thank you for helping and reading.

Comment: To clarify, are $a,b$ variables, or integer values?

Comment: All of them are positive integers, though if they can be extended for negative/other(?) numbers that would be interesting

Comment: Why does you title use absolute value signs?  $\gcd(M,N) = \gcd(M,-N)$ so signs and absolute values don't matter.

Comment: Hint:  $(a+b)^k = a^k + b^k + k(a^{k-1}b + ab^{k-1}) + {k\choose 2}(a^{k-2}b^2 + a^2b^{k-2}) + .....$.

Comment: Dupe of a prior contest question (awaiting mod unclocking of it before closure)

Comment: @fleablood Sorry, how does the hint help? I tried taking mod $a-b$, is that correct? However, I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: @BillDubuque Yes, I realise. However, can I still keep this post here, since that post seems to be locked after two years?

Comment: I think you have answered it in your question.That is only possible iff (a, b)=c.

Comment: What do you mean $(a, b) = c$?